# instalacion xammp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, smtp

Buenas soy nuevo en esto, el caso es que tengo hecha una página web, y  tras vario tiempor me di cuenta que no instale el modulo de mercury del xammp, el caso es que para otra cosa que quiero hacer, necesito un servidor de correo, y me gustaría saber si reinstalar el xammp encima (con todos los modulos) pudiera provocar que perdiera todas mis bases de datos, un saludo.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de si se pierden o no las bases de datos. Lo que si puedes hacer es exportar las bases de datos que tienes y en caso de que se borren volver a importarlas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en mi experiencia si elimina las BDD, yo te sugiero hacer un respaldo de tus bases y tus archivos dentro de la carpeta XAMPP de tu servidor. 
saludos cordiales!.